# How to remove selected items from listview when click remove button in android

Tags: android, android-listview

am displaying names in list view, with check boxes,here i have button if i click that button that  time i need to remove selected items and from list view, remain items only i need to show in list view,using below i code i can find what are the items i selected but i dont know how to remove those, can you any one suggest me

```
MainActivity.class: 
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private ListView listview;  
 ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();  
 private int count;  
 private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;  
 @Override  
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
      fillarray();  
      count = items.size();  
      thumbnailsselection = new boolean[count];  
      listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);  
      listview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this));  
 }  
 private void fillarray() {  
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
      items.clear();  
      items.add("Android alpha");  
      items.add("Android beta");  
      items.add("1.5 Cupcake (API level 3)");  
      items.add("1.6 Donut (API level 4)");  
      items.add("2.0 Eclair (API level 5)");  
      items.add("2.0.1 Eclair (API level 6)");  

 }  
 @Override  
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.  
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);  
      return true;  
 }  
 public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {  
      private LayoutInflater mInflater;  
      private Context mContext;  
      public ImageAdapter(Context context) {  
           mContext = context;  
      }  
      public int getCount() {  
           return count;  
      }  
      public Object getItem(int position) {  
           return position;  
      }  
      public long getItemId(int position) {  
           return position;  
      }  
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
           ViewHolder holder;  
           if (convertView == null) {  
                holder = new ViewHolder();  
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(  
                          R.layout.row_photo, null);  
                holder.textview = (TextView) convertView  
                          .findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);  
                holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView  
                          .findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);  
                convertView.setTag(holder);  
           } else {  
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();  
           }  
           holder.checkbox.setId(position);  
           holder.textview.setId(position);  
           holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
                public void onClick(View v) {  
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
                     CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;  
                     int id = cb.getId();  
                     if (thumbnailsselection[id]) {  
                          cb.setChecked(false);  
                          thumbnailsselection[id] = false;  
                     } else {  
                          cb.setChecked(true);  
                          thumbnailsselection[id] = true;  
                     }  
                }  
           });  
           holder.textview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
                public void onClick(View v) {  
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
                     int id = v.getId();  
                }  
           });  
           holder.textview.setText(items.get(position));  
           holder.checkbox.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);  
           holder.id = position;  
           return convertView;  
      }  

    public void removeItems()
      {
          notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
 }  
 class ViewHolder {  
      TextView textview;  
      CheckBox checkbox;  
      int id;  
 }  
 public void click(View v) {  
      if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {  

           boolean noSelect = false;  

           for (int i = 0; i < thumbnailsselection.length; i++) {  
              if (thumbnailsselection[i] == true) {  
                   noSelect = true;  

                       items.remove(i);

                }  


         }  
          thumbnailsselection = new boolean[items.size()];
         adapter.removeItems(); 
      }  
 }  
}
```

Comment: Get the id / position of the element which you want to remove. Remove it first from your array `array.remove(indexOfObjectWhichYouWantToRemove)` and call `adapter.notifySetDataChanged()`.

Comment: ok..i want to remove multiple selected items same time,when i click delete button

Comment: ok, so just store these positions which you select in an array and depending on them just remove the items from the main array

Comment: ok,thnks..can you see my code delete button onclick once ,i did like that only na

Comment: this code will work only if the items in `thumbnailsselection` and `items` are equal as size and it will remove the right object/item.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following solution

declare this before oncreate

```
ImageAdapter adapter;
```

in your oncreate change the

```
ImageAdapter adapter=new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Inside your ImageAdapter add the following method

```
public void removeItems()
{
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

in your onclick method

```
for (int i = 0; i < thumbnailsselection.length; i++) {  
            if (thumbnailsselection[i] == true) {  
                 noSelect = true;  
                 Log.e("sel pos thu-->", "" + i);  
            //     posSel.add(i);  //
                     items.remove(i);
                 // break;  
            }  
       }  
thumbnailsselection = new boolean[items.size()];
adapter.removeItems();
```

Comment: hi where i add to removwItems() i added inside imageadapter class...its showing invocation target exception

Comment: if add out side of imageadapter menas its asking to create mehod notifyDatachanged

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException in on  adapter.removeItems(); remove line

Comment: yes listdisplaying,if select items from listview then i click delete button..that time am getting nullpointer exception

Comment: removeItems() method should be inside ImageAdapter class

Comment: add - thumbnailsselection = new boolean[items.size()]; before adapter.removeItems();

Comment: i didn't remove removeItems(),and i added thumbnailsselection = new boolean[items.size()]; before adpater.removeItems() now also getting nullpointer exception in this line  adpater.removeItems()

Comment: hi see my main question post i edited....here what ever u said changes that i did... is it correct or else  i did any mistake see once pls

Comment: declare this before oncreate ImageAdapter adapter;
in your oncreate change the
ImageAdapter adapter=new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this)
listview.setAdapter(adapter); i dont see this in your code

Comment: hmm did,but now also sam problem

Answer (score 1):

1. Record the state of all CheckBox.

   - Data type **SparseBooleanArray** is better than **boolean[]** here.
   - Initialize **thumbnailsselection** in **ImageAdapter constructer**, and modify its values in checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new **OnCheckedChangeListener**() {}).

   `// Initialize`

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
       thumbnailsselection.put(i, false);
   ```

   `// Modify`

   ```
   holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
           int position = buttonView.getId();
           thumbnailsselection.put(position, isChecked);
       }
   });
   ```
2. Remove items **from back to front,** one by one, because the deletion only affects indices of items behind the removed one.

   ```
   for (int i = itemCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       position = thumbnailsselection.keyAt(i);
       isChecked = thumbnailsselection.get(position, false);

       if (!isChecked)
           continue;

       if (position < items.size())
           items.remove(position);
   }
   ```
3. Show new data.

   ```
   imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused because I don't think your adapter shows what you want even before deletion because of this:

```
public int getCount() {  
           return count;  
}  
public Object getItem(int position) {  
      return position;  
}
```

Once your adapter will be correctly set with the array of data to display (in your case `items` I think) you just have to remove the objects you want delete from this array (`items.remove(obj)`) and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter.

Edit:

I think there is some logic problems in your code here. I assume that you want display data from an `Array` so you should probably extends `ArrayAdapter` in place of `BaseAdapter`.
Next I think there is a confusion between item and item position. A classical implementation of `getItem()` is, for arrays, something like:

```
public Object getItem(int position) {  
      return array.get(position);  
}
```

Maybe I'm totally wrong, but I think you should first clean your code to fit exactly your needs, and then it will be pretty easy to achieve that you want.

Comment: here what is obj, i need write delete items code inside delete button onclick() only

Comment: `obj` is the string that you wan't delete from the list

Comment: selected items i am storing in one arraylist then i deleted using below

Comment: for(int i1=0;i1<posSel.size();i1++)
                         {
                          items.remove(i1);
                         }

Comment: possel arrylist whatever i am selecting those values is storing

Comment: @radha, I edit my post I think you should think about a different adapter implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code and write it in button click event

```
        SparseBooleanArray checked = keywordsList.getCheckedItemPositions();

        ArrayList<String> selectedKeywords = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
            int position = checked.keyAt(i);
            if (checked.valueAt(i))
                selectedKeywords.add(keywordsAdapter.getItem(position));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < selectedKeywords.size(); i++) {
            keywordsAdapter.remove(selectedKeywords.get(i));
        }

        keywordsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Here my adapter code is like this

```
        keywordsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            IncidentEditActivity.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                            arrKeywords);
        keywordsList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        keywordsList.setAdapter(keywordsAdapter);
```